# How to add custom tags in xslt?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-grouping

can we add custom tag or function in XSLT.I will explain again I added one tag`include-html` in my demo .can we add any logic in XSLT when we find `include-html` in my stylesheet it matches that template with tag value (same as we do in `apply-template`) and get it values and show in output.

here is my code.
http://xsltransform.net/6pS1zDt/1

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="html" doctype-public="XSLT-compat" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
      <hmtl>
        <head>
          <title>New Version!</title>
        </head>
        <include-html>a</include-html>
      </hmtl>
    </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="a">
  <xsl:variable name="ab" select="'ss'"/>
   <p><xsl:value-of select="$ab"/></p>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

In my example I am writing `a` value of `include-html` value.No it match the template and return `**<p>ss</p>**`

```
<include-html>a</include-html>
```

Expected output

```
**<p>ss</p>**
```

Comment: you need to start over https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xsl_intro.asp

Comment: @MatthewWhited i know these thing

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with some kind of *meta stylesheet* (let's name it `test.xslt`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <!-- identity template -->
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>  

    <xsl:template match="/whatever">
      <hmtl>
        <head>
          <title>New Version!</title>
        </head>
        <include-html>a</include-html>
      </hmtl>
    </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="include-html[text()='a']">
    <xsl:variable name="ab" select="'ss'"/>
    <p><xsl:value-of select="$ab"/></p>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

If you pass this to your XSLT processor as XSLT **and** XML input like

```
xsl.sh test.xslt test.xslt
```

the output is

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml"
               omit-xml-declaration="yes"
               encoding="UTF-8"
               indent="yes"/>

    <!-- identity template -->
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>  

    <xsl:template match="/whatever">     <!-- must NOT match -->
      <hmtl>
        <head>
            <title>New Version!</title>
        </head>
        <p>ss</p>                        <!-- REPLACED! -->
      </hmtl>
    </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="include-html[text()='a']">
      <xsl:variable name="ab" select="'ss'"/>
      <p>
         <xsl:value-of select="$ab"/>
      </p>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

which is close to what you want, I suppose...